# Want to refactor following code , it's written in python :

Tags: python

Want to refactor following code , it's written in python :

```
def __init__(self):
    self.var1= Module.ClassA()
    self.var2= Module.ClassB()
    self.var3= Module.ClassC()
    self.var4= Module.ClassD()
    self.var5= Module.ClassE()
    self.var6= Module.ClassF()
    self.var7= Module.ClassG()
    self.var8= Module.ClassH()
    self.var9= Module.ClassI()
    self.var10= Module.ClassJ()
    self.var11= Module.ClassK()
    self.var12= Module.ClassL()
    self.var13= Module.ClassM()
    self.var14= Module.ClassN()
    self.var15= Module.ClassO()
    self.var16= Module.ClassP()
    self.var17= Module.ClassQ()
    self.var18= Module.ClassR()
    self.var19= Module.ClassS()
    self.var20= Module.ClassT()
```

Comment: extremely difficult to read anything out of this code

Comment: And your question is? Please clarify what is wrong with that code and what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Are the actual names in your actual code `Module`, `var`s 1 through 20, and `Class`es A through T?

Comment: Does an `from Module import *` can be enough ?

Comment: My actual requirement is like it , have a python file say TestDebugClass , it has many classes ex. ClassA ...... ClassX . then TestDebugClass imported in another python file say DebugClass , DebugClass has one init function, In init function want to save  each classes (ClassA ...... ClassX ) instance in variable ex: self.var1= Module.ClassA() , then these variable will be used in many places. But when see my init function it looks huge function so want to refactor it

Answer (score 4):

Start refactoring the code you haven't given us:
`ClassF` is a useless name for a class so rename all classes to have meaningful names. `var18` is a useless name for an attribute so refactor all attributes to have meaningful names.

**No** class needs 20 attributes referring to instances of other different classes: refactor the dependencies so that this class only references the objects it actually uses directly.

Comment: Here , i gave example , i can't show my actual code  . But my requirement like it only